# Handling dynamic import with py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, dynamic-import

I have a problem when preparing an .exe for my app using py2exe.
The source of this problem is the following function that I created to use classes from 
a dynamically defined module.

```
def of_import(module, classname, country = None):
    '''
    Returns country specific class found in country module
    '''
    if country is None:
       country = CONF.get('simulation', 'country')
    _temp = __import__(country + '.' + module, 
                       globals = globals(), 
                       locals = locals(), 
                       fromlist = [classname], 
                       level=-1)
    return getattr(_temp, classname, None)
```

When I try to load some class using:

```
self.InputTable = of_import('model.data', 'InputTable')
```

I end up with the following error when running the .exe:

```
File "core\utils.pyc", line 900, in of_import
ImportError: No module named france.model.data
```

I should precise that the france.model.data.py do exist.

What would be the appropriate way to deal with this issue ?

For information here is the link to the setup file : https://github.com/openfisca/openfisca/blob/dev/src/setup_x64.py

Comment: Two questions: Does a `france.model.data.py` module file exist and, if so, does this code only fail after you have compiled it with `py2exe`?

Comment: The relevant code would be your `setup.py` for py2exe. Can we see that? It needs to include the modules, since they will not be discovered automatically by py2exe

Comment: I edited the question to answer @martineau questions

Comment: link added in question to answer @jdi

Comment: Since the module does exist, it sounds like an search path issue. Try setting the `PY2EXE_VERBOSE` environment variable to 1 or 2 as described [here](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/TroubleshootingImportErrors) to further diagnose the problem.

Comment: It would make more sense if your location specific modules were subpackaged under something like "lang" package. Then you would not have to explicitely include all of them in your setup. You just include the "lang" package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar setup

Make sure you add your dynamic modules in the "packages" section of py2exe

```
setup(windows=[{
                "script" : "openFisca.pyw"
                }], 
      options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "encodings.*", "numpy.*"],
                           "packages": ["france","tunisia"],
                           "dist_dir": dist_dir,
                           "bundle_files":3,
                           "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"]
                           }}, 
      data_files=data_files)
```