# No module named drivers.sapi5 when try py2exe

Tags: python, module, driver, executable, py2exe

i'm trying to compile my python application with py2exe, but i try to open the executable file and i get `No module named driver.sapi5` in the main module of my application have a variable `speech_engine = pyttsx.init('sapi5')` define the speech_engine and the imports are

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx
import os
from utilities import *
import time
import datetime
import webbrowser as wb
from datetime import datetime
```

how can i solve this problem ? i'm new with python, i'm trying to do a voice recognition bot

Comment: You may want to debug as [suggested](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/TroubleshootingImportErrors#Debugging_compiled_.exe_with_PY2EXE_VERBOSE) in the docs and post the output you get from that.

Comment: Since this appears to be a dynamic import you may find the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13629321/1072229) useful.